# Node.js MySQL WHERE placeholder with wildcard characters error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am having trouble moving this line from MySQL

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE '?%'`

to my method in node.js

```
    getName(request, respond){
        var columnName = request.params.columnName;
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE '?%'";
        db.query(sql, columnName, function(error, result){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            else{
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

What is the correct syntax for the LIKE '?%'
Thank you so much!

Comment: Try `LIKE CONCAT(?,'%')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks again and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: No its fine. We are all learning here. There's another way of doing this actually and you can try it like this `LIKE '" + columnName + "%'`.. see if this can work

Comment: @tcadidot0 if this was the solution, you should write it as an answer...

Comment: @BillKarwin , which one?

Comment: Your comment showing string-concatenation is not a good recommendation. Please don't encourage people to write _more_ code that contains SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Ok @BillKarwin , I note that. How about the second method?

Comment: I mean the second method has string-concatenation happening in Node.js code. That's the unsafe one. The use of `CONCAT(?, '%')` in the SQL expression is actually safe, because it's using a query parameter.

Comment: Oh no..that's not good... my web app uses that method in all places.. But I must admit that I knew this day would come. Looks like I have to change my method. Thanks for the clarification @BillKarwin

Answer (score 2):

This question is probably answered in various places in Stack Overflow already, but after searching briefly, I couldn't find one with the particular combination of mysql and node.js, so here goes:

You're on the right track using query parameters, but the following won't work, because parameter placeholders can't be inside an SQL string literal. Otherwise, how would you ever use an actual "?" character in an SQL string?

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE '?%'";
```

You can use parameter placeholders only outside the string delimiters, even if the parameter is for a string or date value.

Your options are to concatentate the parameter with a literal `'%'` in an SQL expression like the answer from @tcadidot0:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')";
```

Or alternatively, concatenate the wildcard to your input string in Node.js code, and treat the concatenated value as a single string:

```
var columnNamePattern = request.params.columnName + "%";
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE ?";
db.query(sql, columnNamePattern, function(error, result){
```

Please avoid concatenating Node.js variables into your SQL query. That creates an SQL injection vulnerability.

## NOT SAFE:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE '" + columnName + "%'";
```

It's also more difficult to write code in the unsafe way. It's harder to spot mismatched quotes, it takes longer to write the code, it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `LIKE '?%'` to `LIKE CONCAT(?,'%')`;

```
getName(request, respond){
        var columnName = request.params.columnName;
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName LIKE CONCAT(?,'%')";
        db.query(sql, columnName, function(error, result){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            else{
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```